# Allocate values of one column after the modolus/values of another column

Tags: r, allocation, raster

In order to distribute a certain amount of `TRUE` (=1) values, depending on `raster` layer's values, I would like to do something like this:

Let's say I have a 9x2 matrix looking like this:

```
Example <- matrix(c(0.8,0.6,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.9,0.7,
                0.1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),ncol=2)

     > Example
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  0.8    1
 [2,]  0.6    1
 [3,]  0.5    1
 [4,]  0.3    1
 [5,]  0.2    1
 [6,]  0.4    0
 [7,]  0.9    0
 [8,]  0.7    0
 [9,]  0.1    0
```

Now I want to allocate the `1`'s from `[,2]` as a function of the highest values of `[,1]` **without** changing the order of `[,1]`. The result should look like this:

```
> Example
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  0.8    1
 [2,]  0.6    1
 [3,]  0.5    1
 [4,]  0.3    0
 [5,]  0.2    0
 [6,]  0.4    0
 [7,]  0.9    1
 [8,]  0.7    1
 [9,]  0.1    0
```

Is there any elegant way to do this. I could't find any function to solve this problem. As I want to convert `[,2]` to a `raster` layer using the `raster` package a raster-based solution would work for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find how many `1`'s you have by summing column 2.  You can then find your relative threshold of column 1 by checking if it is higher or lower than that value.

```
how.many.ones <- sum(Example[, 2])

max.thresh <- sort(Example[, 1], decreasing=TRUE)[how.many.ones]

change.to.one <- Example[, 1] >= max.thresh

Example[, 2] <- ifelse(change.to.one, 1, 0)
```

#### RESULTS:

```
Example

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  0.8    1
 [2,]  0.6    1
 [3,]  0.5    1
 [4,]  0.3    0
 [5,]  0.2    0
 [6,]  0.4    0
 [7,]  0.9    1
 [8,]  0.7    1
 [9,]  0.1    0
```

#### Caveat:

There is no tie-handling in this process.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a quite sophisticated solution! I thought there is an existing function for my problem, which I could't find! Thanks a lot @Ricardo Saporta !

Comment: I'd be curious as to what the application here is?

Comment: I have a probability map as raster layer with every pixel representing a certain probability to be urban/not-urban. Now I want to show how a urban area would look like if 10%...100% would be urban on the basis of the probability map.

Comment: so what does column 2 represent?

Comment: Column 2 represents the if a pixel is urban(=1) or not(=0)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
Example[,2]<-ifelse(Example[,1]>=0.5,1,0)
```

But, I'm only guessing that you want the column to be 1 if it is greater or equal to 0.5, and 0 if not.

But maybe you wanted the second column to be the order of the first one. It is a little confusing:

```
Example[,2]<-Example[order(Example[,1]),2]
```